# Paragraph ended before \pgffor@@vars was complete. (\foreach)

Tags: pgfplots, loops, foreach

Until now I always used `\invokepgfplotsforeach{1,...5}` successfully. Since I have some nested dynamic code all using `#1`, `#2`, `#3`, etc., I wanted to name the foreach's variable `#1` by using `\foreach`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \foreach \variable \in {1,3,5} {
            \addplot {\variable*x};
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, even this MWE leads to the following error message:

```
! Paragraph ended before \pgffor@@vars was complete.
```

The same when I am using `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` instead of `\foreach`. What is it missing?

Comment: It's just `in`, not `\in`.

Comment: Really...? Really! Took me hours. Thanks a lot! - Post it as answer and I can mark the question as answered.

Comment: Additionally, I have a follow up question when using group plots: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386988

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As campa said in his comment:

> It's just `in`, not `\in`.