# Missing \endcsname inserted. when \foreach{\nextgroupplot}

Tags: pgfplots, errors, foreach, groupplots

I try to generate a lot of plots, organized in a `groupplot`, automatically. Unfortunately, `\foreach` seems to have a problem with the `\nextgroupplot` macro.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=3 by 1}]
        \foreach \variable in {1,2,3} {
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot {x^\variable};
        }
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This minimal *not working* example crashes with the following message from which I found suggestions about an issue with the macro.

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pgfcrdmth@x 
l.11         }
```

Is there any way to use a loop within a group plot anyway?

Comment: regular TikZ `foreach` is not suitable for such usage due to scoping and other technical details. Encapsulate your code with `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3}{...}` and use `#1` instead of `\variable`

Comment: The initial intention was to replace `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` by `\foreach`/`\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` for naming the variable `#1` because of several nested macros, i. e. `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3}{\nextgroupplot[y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{##1*1000}\pgfmathresult}] \addplot {x^#1};}`. As I understood you that's not possible. If so, I can mark the question as answered after you have copied you comment, which is working, as answer. Thank you!

Comment: You need to double the `#` signs if you need to use them

Comment: That's what I did (see `\pgfmathparse{##1*1000}` above). I wanted to avoid `####1` for even more nested macros.